# How to delete a theme using AJAX

Tags: plugins, php

I want to delete a theme using an AJAX request.

I've looked through the `ajax-actions.php` file and saw this: `wp_ajax_delete_theme()`, but how do I trigger it?

I want to add this 'delete theme' function to my WordPress plugin.

If anyone can explain this to me, it's very much appriciated.

Comment: I don't think you can trigger it, as it's meant to be a WordPress only function. Even if you were to call it, `check_ajax_referer( 'updates' );` would prevent you from running it.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee So why does WordPress restrict us from running these functions? Are there any more possibilities, like copying the functions and making them my own?

Comment: @Mitch they are not restricted, they just tend to mostly be used internally. you don't need to copy the functions just properly provide what wordpress needs to run them - mostly a nonce value, but also must be posted (see answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a post form with a nonce field...

```
$url = admin_url('admin-ajax.php');
echo '<form action="'.$url.'" method='post'>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="action" value="delete_theme">';
wp_nonce_field('updates'); // to pass check_admin_referer
echo '<input type="hidden" name="slug" value="twentythirteen">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete TwentyThirteen Theme">';
echo '</form>';
```

You can replace the hard-coded `slug` input field with a `<select>` one and loop through installed themes to add them as the select options if you like, but I've given it this way because you say you want to delete *a* theme.